# How do you disable specific clang diagnostics via an .xcconfig?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings, clang, compiler-flags

Ok, so say you were getting an error when compiling such as..

> Retain'ed block property does not copy the block - use copy attribute instead

because of...

```
-Wobjc-noncopy-retain-block-property
```

to which you *could fix the problem*, or possibly add a flag such as

```
-Wno-objc-noncopy-retain-block-property
```

But let's further suppose you liked to use "Configuration" (`.xcconfig`) files, and you thought, "OK, since I can use...

```
CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS = NO
```

maybe I'll try.."

```
CLANG_WARN_OBJC_NONCOPY_RETAIN_BLOCK_PROPERTY = NO
```

Only to discover this does NOT work.

So the question <s>retains</s>, umm remains... What DOES work?

Comment: Sorry, typo... yes, that's what I tried.

Comment: Right.. It should be!

Comment: note: these xcode build settings (in all caps) are typically aliases for actual build settings.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode allows you to copy entries from the Build Settings pane using <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>; the result when pasting is the text that corresponds to that setting for use in an .xcconfig file.

When I entered `-Wno-objc-noncopy-retain-block-property` into the "Other Warning Flags" row, and copy-pasted that into a new .xcconfig file, I ended up with this:

```
//:configuration = Debug
WARNING_CFLAGS = -Wno-objc-noncopy-retain-block-property

//:configuration = Release
WARNING_CFLAGS = -Wno-objc-noncopy-retain-block-property
```

and that does indeed seem to supress the warning about a `retain` Block property.

Comment: +1 - you could also drag and drop from the build settings view

Comment: I think what you've said may be "as good as it gets"..  I would just add - that since `WARNING_CFLAGS` may be set in several "places"... that you can _combine them_ (and specify a specific SDK, etc) like... `WARNING_CFLAGS[sdk=macosx*] = $(WARNING_CFLAGS) -Wno-conversion -Wno-objc-noncopy-retain-block-property`...